# AngularJs resposiveness on mobile device

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material, responsiveness

I have created an HTML page using material angularjs which works fine on desktop with different sizes on browser..

But, whenever the same page is opened on mobile device it behaves like desktop application. It does not shows its responsiveness with mobile device size.

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why don't you share your code ? Its hard to understand.

Comment: Please share your code or create a jsFiddle and share the link

Comment: Please have a look on the link shred below. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGMvvX

this code is working fine on desktop with different sizes but it does not shows its responsiveness on mobile device.

Comment: this doesn't even seem to have anything to do with angularjs at all.

Comment: I got the answer...we have to include

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this line of code in your code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```